# Best way to resize image to fit div (as background)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make background, with 85% height and 100% width index page. Actually i am using bootstrap 4. My problem is that when i put image as background into div it will not resize is showed only part of image (image is too big) when i tried to use img property but then my navbar jumped under image. And of course i tried probably everything on internet.
Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/b4.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
<title>Reštaurácia</title>    

</head>

<body>

 <!-- Navigation -->
<div class="bg">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-faded">
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content" aria-controls="nav-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<!-- Brand -->
<a class="navbar-brand mleft" href="#">Reštaurácia</a>

<!-- Links -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse mright" id="nav-content">   
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item active ">
<a class="nav-link ilink" href="#">Domov</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item ">
<a class="nav-link " href="#">Rezervácia</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item ">
<a class="nav-link " href="#">Menu</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item ">
<a class="nav-link " href="#">Galéria</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item ">
<a class="nav-link " href="#">Kontakt</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on aspect ratio you might still experience some cut off, but my two best guesses are:

```
background-size: contain;
```

or

```
background-size: cover;
```

[More info on the background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Happy styling!

Comment: Thanks and is there any best resolution or aspect ratio for image?